# Remove type="text/javascript" from wordpress site

Tags: php, wordpress, html, wordpress-theming

I have a wordpress based site in which I need to remove type="text/javascript" and type="text/css" for scripts and styles in the html head.

I searched in wp_head() and in other files but really can't find the place where exactly this is been from.

Which file has this code?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code on your functions.php

```
add_filter('style_loader_tag', 'remove_type_attr', 10, 2);
add_filter('script_loader_tag', 'remove_type_attr', 10, 2);

function remove_type_attr($tag, $handle) {
    return preg_replace( "/type=['\"]text\/(javascript|css)['\"]/", '', $tag );
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your answer could be improved by adding an explanation of how your answer solves the problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer